# Keypress event firing only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

I am doing like this :

```
$(".classname").bind("keypress",function(){
    alert("event happened");
})
```

code similar to above, working only once, I mean, the first time you type and click enter, it's working, but next time, its not at all reacting.

```
$("#id").bind("keypress",function(){
   alert("haiii");
})
```

the second code working all the time, but the first code working only once.

Also if second code is run once, the first code is not even running once.

What is the solution? I think I am missing some rules here, can you tell them so that I will search about them.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's because you submited the form?

Comment: u mean, do u want me to use e.preventDefault() ?  but preventdefault()  should be used for submit buttons, right ? here if i preventdefault, normal action of input box wont happen, here the element i am referring to is input type=text element

Comment: Try with `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CSVkZ/   i posted code here ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event binder should be always available; if it's not it's because you're changing the HTML structure (either appending or deleting nodes). In your case, you're dynamically changing HTML at runtime, you need to use `.on()`

Try this instead of `.bind()`:

```
    $('#id').on({
       keypress: function () { alert("hi"); }
    });

    $('.ClassName').on({
       keypress: function () { alert("hi"); }
    });

    // IF YOU KNOW CLASSNAME ELEMENTS ARE INSIDE A FIXED ELEMENT:

    $('#FixedID').on({
       keypress: function () { alert("hi"); }
    }, '.ClassName');
```

Regarding your coding style, you should separate the event handlers and the functions that handle the events. For instance, instead of this where the handlers also execute code:

```
// one function that does everything!!
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind events
    $('#SomeID').on({

       click: function () {
         // huge wall of code that handles events
       },
       mouseenter: function () {
         // another huuuuuuuge wall of code here
       }
    )};
});
```

You should have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    BindHandlers();
    DoSomethingElseWithPageInit();
}); 

function BindHandlers() {
// handlers do just the handling of events; easy to see and understand
   $('#SomeID').on({
      click: function (e) { ClickOnSomeID(e); },
      mouseenter: function () { MouseEnterOnSomeID(); }
   )};
}

// here are the functions that process the event
function ClickOnSomeID(e) { ... }
function MouseEnterOnSomeID() { ... }
```

Comment: It's worth adding that, in the case of dynamic elements, you should call `on()` on the closest ancestor to the target elements that exist in the DOM at the time of DOMReady.

Comment: @DavidThomas: yes, of course! The OP didn't supply his HTML structure; made edit

Comment: may b ur right, but in my case, its not working , but what i know is, in backbone.js , i use delegateEvents() method to stop these kind of problems, but here i am not getting wat to do ..

Comment: Put your code in jsfiddle so we can take a closer look at the problem. The .on() is the way to go; works like a charm.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CSVkZ/   i have written in coffeescript, converted into javascript using coffee compiler,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CSVkZ/   in this link, if u can see , the text box  with "new list" button is working always, but the textbox inside that grey box, working only once

Comment: i got the answer , live method is working :

     $(".classname").live("keypress",function(){

      alert("keypressed");

     });

Comment: .live() will be deprecated soon; .on() is the new method introduced in jquery 1.7 designed to replace .live() and .delegate(). If you use .live() and in a year from now someone updates the jquery file to the latest version, your code might break if it can't find .live()

Comment: ok, but can u tell me, why "on" is not working and "live" is working ?

Comment: What's the jsfiddle with the working .live() implementation? I've also had some issues the first time I converted to .on() because the syntax is a little different.

Comment: ok, I'm assuming the last posted jsfiddle is the most up-to-date version. I fixed the function syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/CSVkZ/1/ Also, as a matter of style, you should separate the event handling from the function handling the event. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As frenchie notes, it's because your html structure has changed. This has been treated right by .live(), but now .on() is the successor.
But you should use on() not on the element, but on the document:

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#id", function(){
alert("event happened");
})
```