# $.ajax interfering with .hide() and .show() Jquery in this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(In Firefox and IE9 it doesn't work. In Chrome, this works)

If I remove the ajax, the hide / show JQuery works. Any solutions?

```
<form id="ppform" action="blah.asp" method="post">
<div id="saleload">Blah</div>
<button id="sendbutton">Send</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#saleload').hide();

    $('#sendbutton').click(function() {

        $('#saleload').show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: /blah/blah.asp,
            data: reqBody,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data,textStatus){ 

                if (data.redirect) {
                   window.location.href = data.redirect;
                }else{
                    $("#ppform").replaceWith(data.form);
                }
             }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Is `#saleload` inside `#ppform`?

Comment: @bfavaretto: most likely that's the problem.

Comment: Yes it is. It's in the form container of #ppform

Comment: Then when you're replacing the HTML, you're also wiping out the event handler. Use jquery .on() instead of .bind() for your event handlers when you're changing the HTML at runtime.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689686/keypress-event-firing-only-once/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious reason is that there is an error with your Javascript that causes the whole section not to execute. Quickly looking through your code shows this line:

```
        url: /blah/blah.asp,
```

Strings need to be enclosed in quotation marks:

```
        url: "/blah/blah.asp",
```

Comment: The comments above re replacing elements are also relevant to making your code function correctly. Without this change, however, your code will not function at all.

Comment: *Smacks self in the head* Forgot to put it in quotation marks. Thanks

Comment: @Patriotec, this will solve your first problem (remember to look at the javascript console next time!). Now you'll face some new ones. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
$("#ppform").replaceWith(data.form);
```

is replacing the whole form contents with the response from your Ajax request. This means the click handler you setup will be gone too, because `#sendbutton` will be gone. Even if you have another button with the same ID inside `data.form`, it won't work. You have to use event delegation instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#saleload').hide();
    $(document).on('click', '#sendbutton', function(){
        $('#saleload').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/blah/blah.asp",
            data: reqBody,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data,textStatus){ 
                if (data.redirect) {
                   window.location.href = data.redirect;
                } else {
                    $("#ppform").replaceWith(data.form);
                }
             }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Also: you seem to be posting an undefined variable `reqBody` to your server, and, as lonesomeday said above, you were missing quotes around the URL.

Comment: Yes, this solves the real problem of the code: dynamic event handling when the HTML is updated at runtime.

Comment: @frenchie, thanks for your support. Yes, this solves one of the problems, but the one pointed out by lonesomeday is not less "real". It seems the OP didn't even have the chance to experience the problem we were talking about, a syntax error was preventing the ajax call to run.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your post. Lonesome was quick. I do believe your code solves all my issues.